# Get ID of all child elements and its input/select data

Tags: javascript, jquery, children

How can I get the `id` of each child element and its tag name so I can save the data of each column to a string?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="poz-3" placeholder="numv" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="poz-3" placeholder="numv" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="poz-3-s">
            <option value="1">-Pick-</option>
            <option value="2">test2</option>
            <option value="3">test3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've got the loop so far, but I don't know how to get the data depending on the input/select:

```
for (var j = 0; j < (nCols / nRows); j++) {
}
```

Comment: Can you show the result you're hoping to obtain, then we know what end-result we're working towards.

Comment: what exactly you want?

Comment: i want to get the data from each column (col-md-4) and save it to a string, so for example: numv, numv, test2 and the problem i face s i ahve a few inputs and a few selects...

Comment: You should give your inputs a `name` attribute - then you can use `$(":input").serialize()`

Comment: What i would need the most is the tag name of each child of col-md-4 so each iteration of loop i can save the value to my string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `.find('*')` to get all the childs :

```
$('.row').find('*').each(function(){
    //Get the id and value
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.row').find('*').each(function(){
    if($(this).prop('tagName')!='OPTION')
      console.log("id = "+$(this).prop('id')+" / value = "+$(this).val());
  else
    console.log("id = "+$(this).prop('id')+" / value = "+$(this).text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="poz-3" placeholder="numv" type="text" value='first input'>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="poz-3" placeholder="numv" type="text" value='second input'>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="poz-3-s">
            <option value="1">-Pick-</option>
            <option value="2" selected>test2</option>
            <option value="3">test3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, just got 1 more question, that returns values for each input type, but if its a select i need it to be a .text() not .val() how would i solve that?

Comment: You need to return the text of select onption's?

Comment: Oh, one more thing, i noticed its still not working as intended, if i use tagName check it writes out all values in select instead of the one that ws picked...

Comment: You could check for the selects tages `if( $(this).prop('tagName')=='SELECT' )` the get the selected option text using `$('option:selected',this).text()`.

Comment: One more question, could i make the loop got throught 1st row and get data from ll of its columns, then ROW2 and after that ROW3, etc... ?

Comment: Yes sure you could use `$('.row').each(function(){ $(this).find('*').each(function(){ })  });`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you can get all input's values simply by iterating through them with jQuery:

```
$.each($('.col input, .col select'), function(index, item) {
    console.log('ELEMENT ID ' + $(item).attr('id') + ' VAL - ' + $(item).val());
});
```

of simply use [serializeArray](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) method like this:

```
$('input, select').serializeArray()
```

Working example of both ways here: https://jsfiddle.net/hc882g27/

P.S.: in pure javascript it could be done with [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) function:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.col input, .col select');

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  console.log(items[i].value);
}
```